# Processing .fil file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwOuV.png)**I have one file with extension .fil**
Its supposed to have xml content in it
I want to read this file by python and extract xml data from it
Tried reading the file using binary format but no results
Any suggestion/guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details. How do you know it's XML? The image you provided does not help.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html? Also, if the file is in plain text format, you could just confirm its .xml format by just opening it with notepad for example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tzane Element tree will work on xml files. For my case I have .fil file which is a kind of binary file and I need to extract xml file from it..Once I get this xml file I can apply logic of parsing with ElementTree